# Edit a mounted Linux image

Tags: linux, mount

I have a Linux image mounted on another Linux system. I need to run command like 'e2label' on the image only.(Not the system on which this image is mounted). Can this be achieved by any means?

Comment: What kind of an image do you have, a raw disk image? Does it contain a partition table or just the ext file system?

Comment: It was a raw disk image, which i converted on the partiotion (on the host system using dd command).

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question... Did you do a dd of a single partition like /dev/sda5 or of a full disk?

Comment: dd was on an entire partition. Linux residing on this partition has partition table. I can mount partitions from this image on the Host machine and edit/create files. Is is possible to run commands like e2label to affect Linux in image (not the Host Linux).

Comment: what is the disk name for which dd u have done

Answer (score 0):

e2label can be used for partition labelling why can't you do just a rename image with mv command mv eg.iso eg.iso

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: I need to make a few changes in the Linux image presently mounted on some Linux machine and then upload it to EC2. I want to do partition labeling in the Mounted Linux OS only.

Comment: For labeling a Linux partition you can use e2label command, tune2fs or else mke2fs command. Each will support ext2 and ext3 filesystems. e2label can be used fro displaying the filesystem label also. Each volume label can have a maximum of 16 characters. And this label will be retained to the filesystem or partition even if you reconnected the hard disk to another controller or even another computer. So if you have mounted a linux iso image to a folder and going to create a new iso out of it, then you can label the new iso while using mkisofs too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant a virtual machine image, best way to do this is to use qemu-nbd which allows you to directly access partitions on the image itself under /dev/nbd0...20 , that way you could alter partitions in the image directly.